# Mutex in rails API among several client request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mutual-exclusion

I face a problem with mutual exclusion in my rails API.
I have some Event object in my database which contain the number of person who will attend the event.

Consider my Event method which add a person to the event :

```
class Event
    def add_person
        nb = self.number_of_person + 1
        # Some stuff
        self.number_of_person = nb
        self.save
    end
end
```

Now, imagine that client A and B want to participate in the event E.
Rails is gonna receive 2 request and will call the add_person method in parallel.
At the end, it is possible that the number of person in the Event E be not incremented by 2 but by 1.

This is what I want to be able to do :

```
Client A                 | Client B                 | Possible in parallel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Event.find(1).show       | Event.find(1).show       | yes
Event.find(1).add_person | Event.find(1).add_person | no
Event.find(1).add_person | Event.find(2).add_person | yes
```

I only want to queue the `add_person` method on the same object.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: en-queue the events then have one worker process them.  Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard ActiveRecord transaction will prevent deadlock, or other contention.  You might have to use a [pessimistic locking strategy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).  Databases are designed to prevent exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it could help. But I don't want only lock the access to the database, I want to lock a method of an Object. I want that Event.find(1).add_person can be not executed in parallel, but that Event.find(1) be possible (only to read informations for example). I want also that Event.find(1).add_person and Event.find(2).add_person be possible.

Comment: Use transactions. They will ensure consistency and integrity exactly as you require.